# Usability - How to display create, edit, view, and search in menu?

Tags: web-applications, usability, crud

I have a web application that allows the user to immediately do one of two things:

1) Search for records

OR

2) Create a new record

As a result, I have two links in the menu bar called Search and Create. If you click on the link, it takes you to the search or create page respectively.

After searching records and selecting a specific record from the search results grid, the user can choose to edit or view the selected record. Note: The search results provide a subset of the record data.

When the user chooses to edit or view:

Should I take the user to a new page and

a) create a new menu bar link called Edit or View

b) rename the Create menu item to Edit or View and once the user is finished rename back to Create

Or is there a more usable (intuitive) way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

What happens if they hit "create" while viewing something?  That should still work; you don't want to remove or rename "create".

The create, edit, and view pages should be pretty darn similar; create and edit might be identical forms.

That said:

The menu bar has two options, "Create" and "Search".

Under the menu bar and before the content should probably be a page title: the four possible titles here are: "Create", "Search", "Search->View", and "Search->Edit".

Clicking on Create always takes you to create something new.
Clicking on Search always takes you to a new search.